# Google Sheet Script (Email to PDF) suddenly sending corrupt PDFs

Tags: pdf, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a Google Sheet Script that sends the page to an email as a PDF which has been working perfectly until yesterday. Suddenly it started sending corrupted PDF's that can not be opened.

The Script runs just fine, if just can not open up the PDF file as it says "Can Not Display - Invalid format".

Any ideas on why it may have stopped working?

```
function sendSheetToPdfwithA1MailAdress(){ // this is the function to call
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sh = ss.getSheets()[0]; // it will send sheet 0 which is the first sheet in the spreadsheet.
  // if you change the number, change it also in the parameters below
  var shName = sh.getName()
    
  // This function uses a cell in the spreadsheet that names the file that is being saved as getfilename().  using this function will pull from a certain Cell (G4 in this case)
function getFilename() {

    var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();

    var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('N1944E'); // Edit the sheet name as necessary

    var cell = sheet.getRange('C8'); //Cell to pull file name from.
    var filename = cell.getValue();

    return filename;
} 

  sendSpreadsheetToPdf(0, shName, sh.getRange('C6').getValue(),"Air Attack Daily Fire Sheet " + getFilename() );
}
function sendSpreadsheetToPdf(sheetNumber, pdfName, email,subject, htmlbody) {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var spreadsheetId = spreadsheet.getId()  
  var sheetId = sheetNumber ? spreadsheet.getSheets()[sheetNumber].getSheetId() : null;  
 var url_base = spreadsheet.getUrl().replace(/edit$/,'');



  var url_ext = 'export?exportFormat=pdf&format=pdf'   //export as pdf

      + (sheetId ? ('&gid=' + sheetId) : ('&id=' + spreadsheetId)) 
      // following parameters are optional...
      + '&size=A4'      // paper size
      + '&portrait=true'    // orientation, false for landscape
      + '&fitw=true'        // fit to width, false for actual size
      + '&sheetnames=true&printtitle=false&pagenumbers=true'  //hide optional headers and footers
      + '&gridlines=false'  // hide gridlines
      + '&fzr=false';       // do not repeat row headers (frozen rows) on each page

  var options = {
    headers: {
      'Authorization': 'Bearer ' +  ScriptApp.getOAuthToken(),
    }
  }

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url_base + url_ext, options);
  var blob = response.getBlob().setName(pdfName + '.pdf');
  if (email) {
    var mailOptions = {
      attachments:blob, htmlBody:htmlbody
    }
MailApp.sendEmail(
      email, 
      subject+" (" + pdfName +")", 
      "html content only", 
      mailOptions);

MailApp.sendEmail(
      Session.getActiveUser().getEmail(), 
      " "+subject+" (" + pdfName +")", 
      "html content only", 
      mailOptions);
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you make a PDF document that gives this error message available? Perhaps the nature of the corruption would give a clue.

Comment: @DavidvanDriessche Here is a link of a PDF that I can not open. You may need to download it from Google Drive. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1EnKhZg5vO-aMOCmoDxaQ3IEamVkzuotg/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had the exact same issue, but I just figured it out.  The problem is here:

```
var url_base = ss.getUrl().replace(/edit$/,'') + "export?";
```

getUrl() appears to be returning a different version of the url than it was before.  It now appends the following on the url: "ouid=###########&urlBuilderDomain=YOURDOMAIN"  check it out yourself by using the logger.

That is causing an issue with the pdf export.  So I built my own url address by replacing that line with the following:

```
var url_base = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/" + ss.getId() + "/" + "export?";
```

It now seems to be working!  Here's the full code that generates my blob:

```
function generatePDF(pdfName, sheet, portrait){
  var token = ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();
  var params = {
    headers: {
      'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token,
    },
    'muteHttpExceptions' : true
  };
  
  var sheetId = sheet.getSheetId();
  var ss = sheet.getParent();
  
  
//  var url_base = ss.getUrl().replace(/edit$/,'') + "export?";
  var url_base = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/" + ss.getId() + "/" + "export?";
  
  var url_ext = 'exportFormat=pdf'   //export as pdf
  + '&format=pdf'     //export as pdf
  + '&gid=' + sheetId
  + '&size=letter'      // paper size
  + '&portrait=' + portrait    // orientation, false for landscape
  + '&fitw=true'        // fit to width, false for actual size
  + '&sheetnames=false'  //optional headers and footers
  + '&printtitle=false'  //optional headers and footers
  + '&pagenumbers=true'  //page numbers
  + '&gridlines=true'  // gridlines
  + '&fzr=true'       // repeat row headers (frozen rows) on each page
  
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url_base + url_ext, params);
  var blob = response.getBlob().setName(pdfName + ".pdf");
  
  return blob;
}
```

Comment: Do you suspect that I am having the exact same issue as you did? What line in my code do you suspect is off?

Comment: I do suspect that.  
Change this :    [var url_base = spreadsheet.getUrl().replace(/edit$/,'');]        
to this:     [var url_base = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/" + spreadsheet.getId() + "/";]

Comment: Now I get: "Exception: Request failed for http://docs.google.com returned code 404. Truncated server response: <!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en"><head><meta name="description" content="Web word processing, presentations and spreadsheets"><meta name="viewport" c... (use muteHttpExceptions option to examine full response) (line 47, file "Code")"

Comment: Fixed it! Your code was missing a "/" which led to my trouble.  ```var url_base = "docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/" + spreadsheet.getId() + "/"; ``` Nice find!! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function sendSpreadsheetToPdf(sheetNumber, pdfName, email,subject, htmlbody) {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var spreadsheetId = spreadsheet.getId()  
  var sheetId = sheetNumber ? spreadsheet.getSheets()[sheetNumber].getSheetId() : null;  
  var url_base = "docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d" + spreadsheetId + "/export?";
  var url_ext = 'exportFormat=pdf&format=pdf'   //export as pdf
  
  + (sheetId ? ('&gid=' + sheetId) : ('&id=' + spreadsheetId)) 
  // following parameters are optional...
  + '&size=A4'      // paper size
  + '&portrait=true'    // orientation, false for landscape
  + '&fitw=true'        // fit to width, false for actual size
  + '&sheetnames=true&printtitle=false&pagenumbers=true'  //hide optional headers and footers
  + '&gridlines=false'  // hide gridlines
  + '&fzr=false';       // do not repeat row headers (frozen rows) on each page
  
  var options = {
    headers: {
      'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken(),
    },
    'muteHttpExceptions' : true
  }
  
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url_base + url_ext, options);
  var blob = response.getBlob().setName(pdfName + '.pdf');
  if (email) {
    var mailOptions = {
      attachments:blob, htmlBody:htmlbody
    }
    MailApp.sendEmail(
      email, 
      subject+" (" + pdfName +")", 
      "html content only", 
      mailOptions);
    
    MailApp.sendEmail(
      Session.getActiveUser().getEmail(), 
      " "+subject+" (" + pdfName +")", 
      "html content only", 
      mailOptions);
  }
}
```

Comment: I feel like we are close. I replaced my half of code with your half and it executes, but I get no email at all now. I use "C6" to enter the email address which I want to send it to. So somehow your code isnt working with mine. I might have to start from scratch again.

Comment: Yeah we are approaching the actual email process differently, but the concept of retrieving the sheet as a pdf file is there.  You just need to modify the code to meet your needs.  Try Logging the "response" variable after executing the url fetch and see what it says.  If there is an error it should appear there and give you an idea of what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this instead of your current blob declaration :

```
var blob = response.getBlob().getAs('application/pdf').setName(pdfName + ' .pdf');
```

References:

[Class Blob](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/blob)

Comment: I replaced this:   ```var blob = response.getBlob().setName(pdfName + '.pdf'); ```
 with this:  ``` var blob = response.getAs('application/pdf').setName(pdfName + ' .pdf),  ```  and then I get this error: Invalid or unexpected token (line 49, file "Code.gs")Dismiss

Comment: Unfortunately I am still getting a corrupted PDF in my email box. Code is running fine, but the PDF is corrupted.

Comment: Same issue. It did not change anything.